# erro na criação da chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira, constraint

estou estudando banco e minha chave estrangeira não cria, sei que estou fazendo algo de errado, mas não consigo entender o que há.

essas são as tableas que quero 'ligar'

```
create table tb_cardapio(
cd_cardapio int not null auto_increment,
nm_tipo varchar(100),
cd_comida int,
constraint fk_cardapio
    primary key (cd_cardapio),
constraint fk_cardapio_comida
    foreign key(cd_comida)
        references tb_cardapio(cd_comida)
);

create table tb_comida(
cd_comida int not null primary key auto_increment,
nm_comida varchar(100),
vl_comida double
);
```

Comment: você está referenciando a propria tabela, essa linha `references tb_cardapio(cd_comida)` deveria ser `references tb_comida(cd_comida)`, e o create da table "tb_comida" deveria estar primeiro

Comment: ah, ok! muito obrigada!